# how to connect to a mongodb via ssh using mac terminal

Tags: macos, mongodb, ssh

I'm new to mongodb and I need to connect to a mongo database that is on a server which I connect via ssh using mac terminal.

I've been reading about the subject and so far I didn't find anything that tells how to do what I need.

Would you have a link that answers that?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as simple as this:

```
mymac$ ssh mymongoserver
mymongoserver$ mongo
```

So you just connect to remote server via SSH and then locally call Mongo console.